# maven-indexer ignores war files

Tags: maven, war, maven-indexer

I'm using the BasicUsageExample to retrieve all artifacts from a Nexus repository:

https://github.com/apache/maven-indexer/blob/master/indexer-examples/indexer-examples-basic/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/indexer/examples/BasicUsageExample.java

Problem is, that I'm looking for war files especially, but those seem to be ignored. Can anybody tell me how to receive as well?

Comment: 10 sec looking at the code and we see this `we want "jar" artifacts only` comment.

Comment: I'm using the "dump all the gavs" part above.

Comment: You've said that you are using `BasicUsageExample` in which "dump all the GAVs" part isn't executed. If you've written some code based on this example then we need to see your code.

Comment: Had to Update the Nexus index manually. Thought the index would be updated each time a new artifact gets deployed, but that seems to be wrong. Using the REST API to update index and maven-indexer to download the index afterwards now.